# How to get the € euro sign on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity, and I am wondering how I can assign the euro sign (`€`) to one of my keys. I knew how to do it on older versions of Ubuntu, but I don't know now.

When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> it shows the $ sign. But I would also like to get the euro sign... maybe if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my keyboard layout "English (International with Dead keys)" I can get the € sign using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>. For a sure kill use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, you will get a underscored u, then type `20ac` <kbd>Space</kbd> and you will get `€`.

Comment: how did you get altgr + 5 to be euro?

Comment: Oh I pressed AltGr + 4 and the € sign showed up! Thank you!

Comment: AltGr+5 or 4 makes Chrome jump to the 5th or 4th tab... Ctrl+Shift+U plus Unicode euro sign number was a sure kill indeed

Answer (score 9):

The actual keyboard-shortcut depends on your keyboard layout. Here is a list of possible shortcuts:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (UK)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (US)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (BEL/ESP/FRA/GER/ITA/POR)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (HU/PL)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> works on all layouts
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in the Vim text editor

As @Fred-Jan [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/791217/1736), if you have a generic English layout, change it to `English (US, with euro on 5)` or `English (US, alternative international)` to be able to use the right ALT key to make the Euro sign.

Answer (score 2):

On keyboard layout "English (UK)" <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> should give you a € symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You could also change your keyboard layout to `English (US, with euro on 5)` or `English (US, alternative international)`, then you will be able to get a `€` symbol by pressing  <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

Comment: This is ment as a solution for people without a AltGr key.

Comment: This did the trick for me.
Luckily @mniess mentioned you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign a character with a key without changing the keyboard layout
alternatively you can open dash (search) and search for `character map`
you will find all the characters

Answer (score 0):

Compose key combination is somewhat handy.

<kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd>=</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd>

This works almost always, doesn't matter the Desktop Environment and language settings.